# How to inline/include css in a react library package

Tags: reactjs, npm, less

I'm trying to build a react component library that I can use in  other applications and I'm running into an issue of packaging css/less with the component library.

in the component library package:

`component.tsx`

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import styles from "./component.less";

const TestComponent: React.FC  = (): ReactElement => {
    ....

    return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
            ....
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

`component.less`

```
@bg-color: #428bca;

.root {
    background-color: @bg-color;
}
```

I run the below commands to build the library:

```
> tsc --emitDeclarationOnly
> lessc src/component.less dist/library.css
> babel src --out-dir dist --extensions .ts,.tsx --source-maps
> copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.less dist/
```

and in the `dist` directory get this:

```
> index.d.ts
> index.js
> library.css
> component.less
> ....
```

in a different application I just install the library and use the component:

```
import TestComponent from "library-package";

<TestComponent /> // in the render somewhere
```

and when I start this application the component is rendered but the css/less code is not applied and not imported.

I'd like to include some default css inside of the library package. And I know that I could just include the `library.css` in the `index.tsx` of an application and the css could work, but I don't want the other application to have to include a css file or have a less loader to handle the css if it doesn't use less itself.

I assume that the problem currently is that the application doesn't know how to handle `.less` files from the library because it doesn't have a less loader setup (although I don't get an error about anything)

tldr: an application would just install the component library, include the component in a render and the component will render with some css (preferrably using less in the library). Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was looking for something like the [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) but using `less` + minifying instead of writing the CSS in a JavaScript file and wrapping HTML tags.

With the styled-components library I got it to work this way:

`component.tsx`

```
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import cssesc from "cssesc";
import styled, { ThemeProvider, DefaultTheme  } from "styled-components";

export interface TestComponentTheme extends DefaultTheme {
    backgroundColor?: string;
}

const DEFAULT_THEME: TestComponentTheme = {
    backgroundColor: "#428bca",
};

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    background-color: ${props => cssesc(props.theme.backgroundColor)};
`;

interface TestComponentInput {
    theme?: TestComponentTheme;
}

const TestComponent: React.FC<TestComponentInput> = ({theme}: TestComponentInput ): ReactElement => {
    ....

    let componentTheme: TestComponentTheme = Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_THEME);

    if (theme) {
        componentTheme= Object.assign({}, componentTheme, theme);
    }

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={componentTheme}>
            <StyledDiv>
                ....
            </StyledDiv>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

building the library requires just two steps now:

```
> tsc --emitDeclarationOnly
> babel src --out-dir dist --extensions .ts,.tsx --source-maps
```

and there are no CSS files in the `dist` directory anymore:

```
> index.d.ts
> index.js
> ....
```

in a different application I just install the library and use the component (which renders with the CSS inline):

```
import TestComponent from "library-package";

<TestComponent /> // in the render somewhere
```

and optionally I can overwrite the CSS of the component:

```
import TestComponent, { TestComponentTheme } from "library-package";

const customTheme: TestComponentTheme = {
    backgroundColor: "#000fff",
};

<TestComponent theme={customTheme} /> // in the render somewhere
```